# htaccess wildcard redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an htaccess wildcard redirect on a website, it redirect another domain to a main one and also redirects www to none www with wildcard for the main domain. The following rules are made with cpanel, however it does not use the wildcard.

These same rules work fine on many other sites just not the one in question.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.ca$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas? I am out of ideas for what could be causing this.

To add more clarification:
if i go to `www.domain1.ca/some-page` it should redirect to `domain1.ca/some-page`
However instead it goes to `domain1.ca`.

Tested in every browser, remade the rules, removed all cache and did multiple dns flush's, nothing has changed this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Causes the same problem.

Comment: ignores the wildcard, www.domain1.ca/hello goes to domain1.ca. rather then domain1.ca/hello.

Comment: That is definitely not happening in these rules, test in a new browser.

Comment: first thing I did, deleted all cache and did a dns flush, i do understand this "should" work I am just totally lost as to why it is not :'(

Comment: Yes, Joomla, although based on what we can see the redirect is happening before its passed to PHP.

Comment: Ok in that case make sure above 301 rules are your very first rules and I don't know Joomla that well but make sure it is not stripping `/hello` to `/` after redirection.

Comment: Yes, we have done that. Even took an htaccess from a fresh install and applied the rules again to it.

Comment: Open your page in Firebug and try request `www.domain1.ca/hello`. See what you get in Net tab

Comment: It records and shows all the different requests (even after reload)